# How Do You Rename a Table in Bigtable?

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable, table-rename

I'm trying to rename a table in Google's Bigtable but can't find anything on how to do it.

However, [renaming a table in HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966073/820410) can be done via [snapshots](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots), but it is [not available in Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences#snapshots).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to rename a table in Cloud Bigtable as of yet.  It does not have a rename method, nor does it have a Snapshot API.  You would have to copy over the data into a new table using Dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename a table in Cloud Bigtable. However, there's a quite convenient method to workaround this limitation:

- Create a backup of the old table
- Restore the backup to the new table
- Delete the old table